# Use drawableRight of EditText as anchor

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to use the `drawableRight` of `EditText` as an anchor view for something. 
But there isn't any method to get `drawableRight`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: `editText.getCompoundDrawables()[2]` gets the current right drawable.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically :

```
edt.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_right, 0, 0);

edt.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_right), null);
```

XML :

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_right"
```